# Flask-SQLAlchemy Attribute Error 'SignallingSession' object has no attribute 'main'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm currently trying my hand at Flask-SQLAlchemy and I'm running into the following problem when it comes to running the commit() method:

First, here is my User class:

```
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin
from flask_sqlalchemy import Model, SQLAlchemy
from app import db


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

  def __init__(self, id, name, password, active):
      self.id = id
      self.name = name
      self.password = password
      self.active = active

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
  password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
  active = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)

  @property
  def is_active(self):
      return self.active
```

Now my main app:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.sqlite'
app.secret_key = b'test'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


from user import User

db.create_all()
db.session.commit() # This commit works fine! 

admin = User(1, 'admin', 'admin', True)
db.session.add(admin)
db.session.commit() # <------ Value Error at this position

print(User.query.all())
```

And I get the following Error message when I try to run my code:

```
in flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py
before_models_committed.send(session.main, changes=list(d.values()))
AttributeError: 'SignallingSession' object has no attribute 'main'
```

I am using Pycharm and the version of flask_sqlalchemy is 2.5.1
Am I using the module wrong?

Thank you for every helpfull comment!

Kind regards,
Bagheera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I don't know if this really counts as a solution, but I tried lowering the version of the flask_sqlalchemy module.

After this didn't work either, because now other error messages appeared, I set the version back to the highest.

After that it worked in a mysterious way. But maybe someone has an explanation for this or experienced something similar.